# How do I add an element to an existing property map in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this piece of code to create a property map that I will pass to jQuery:

```
var myMap = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3};
```

However, this isn't complete. I want to iterate through a `for` loop and create a complex property map, that looks like this:

```
[...
{
  sleep: 2,
  fade: 1
}, [
  { src: 'sand-castle.jpeg' },
  { src: 'sunflower.jpeg'   },
  { src: 'flip-flops.jpeg'  },
  { src: 'rubber-ring.jpeg' }
]
```

I'm iterating through the list of files in the directory. How do I do this?

Comment: One easy workaround is to construct the entire property map as an assignment in a string and `eval()` it, but I'd really like to know how to natively add/remove/change property map elements.

Comment: Can show show the input and desired result?  That may be much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var _map=[];
var _prop={/*an object*/}
var _prop2={/*another object*/}

_map.push(_prop);
_map.push(_prop2);
```